# Rails - Fields from user form detected but validation still fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in UsersController#create
Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank
```

But, the parameters seem to be picked up correctly:

**Request**

```
Parameters

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"l4gsQ/dO9+482Yf1Eq+MBSEVT9zcG4XdN37h1ZhnEIM=",
     "user"=>{"email"=>"d@email.com",
     "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
     "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
     "username"=>"studentd",
     "teacher"=>"Example"},
     "commit"=>"Sign up",
     "format"=>"user"}
```

Here is my `create` method in the UsersController. I am using `Devise` for authentication, but still have a UsersController mainly because it was easier for me to understand.

```
def create
    @user = User.create(:email => params[:email], :password => params[:password], 
      :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation], :username => params[:username],
      :teacher => params[:teacher], :role => "student")
    @user.save!
end
```

I know that `create` is supposed to save for you, but if I do not explicitly call it then the User model is not saved into the database.

Finally, here is the form I am trying to get data from. The use case here is that an `admin` user will be using this to sign up `students`.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :teacher %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :teacher %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice your `:params` hash, you'll see that the user form is itself submitted as a hash under the `user` key.

So `params[:email]` is actually empty. You should be doing `params[:user][:email]`.

Further, you can make your controller action even simple:

```
def create
   @user = User.create(params[:user])
   @user.role = "student"
   @user.save!
end
```

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer, Ive been pulling my hair out over this lol. Thanks!